# An error occurs while I'm trying to run my test

Tags: java, android, appium

I'm learning how to operate Appium to automate one of the apps I test.
I've been watching a course on the Udemy, I've been doing everything as the teacher does. 
Currently I can't even install an app with Appium. 
Here're the errors I get:

```
> error: Logcat capture failed: spawn "E:\Soft\Android_SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" ENOENT
> info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
```

There was a warning before:

```
warn: The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set to the Android SDK root directory path. ANDROID_HOME is required for compatibility with SDK 23+. Checking along PATH for adb.
> info: [debug] executing cmd: where adb
> info: [debug] Using adb from E:\Soft\Android_SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

An here's my code:

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class InstallApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy_Tab_S2");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Users\\Viter\\Downloads\\com.App.apk");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.App");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "md52c.MainActivity");
        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code or is there a problem with something else?

Thanks for your response!

PS: I read that some guys were getting the same error until they changed Android SDK folder name to one without spaces. I did it too. It didn't help :(
PSS: I added Android SDK, Android SDK\tools, Android SDK\platform-tools to System Variables. Just to clarify this question from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself. 
Installed most of the possible options for Android SDK.